# Node / Mysql async datas

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, async-await

I would like to see the messages in order (one, two, three, four ).
Because at the moment my script doesn't work because the request doesn't have time to finish.

At the moment the code return ONE THREE FOUR TWO 
I think it's problem because I don't use async and await but I don't understand where and how used

```
function dropAll() {
  console.log("ONE");

  db.query("SHOW tables", (err, result) => {
    result.map(async list => {
      db.query(`DROP TABLE \`${list.Tables_in_gcd_updt}\``, (err, results) => {
        console.log(list.Tables_in_gcd_updt + " REMOVED");

        console.log("TWO");
      });
    });
  });
}

function getAll() {
  console.log("FOUR");
}

const infiniteQuestion = function() {
  prompt.question("What do you want to your DB project ?", answer => {
    switch (answer) {
      case "drop":
        dropAll();
        console.log("THREE");
        getAll();
        infiniteQuestion();
        break;
      case "exit":
        console.log(`${answer} unknow`);
        rl.close();
        process.exit(0);
      default:
        infiniteQuestion();
    }
  });
};

infiniteQuestion();
```

Thanks

Comment: If you want to use `await`/`async` then you should switch to a `mysql` module that supports Promises e.g. [mysql2 - Promise wrappers](https://github.com/sidorares/node-mysql2/blob/master/documentation/Promise-Wrapper.md), [mysql-promise](https://github.com/martinj/node-mysql-promise#readme) or use [`util.promisify`](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest/docs/api/util.html#util_util_promisify_original) to do that step yourself.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

As you thought, the usage of async/await is required here as the execution of your `dropAll` method is asynchronous.

You can refer to this [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Instructions/async_function) to understand how async/await should be used.

Your example could be updated to the following :

```js
function promisifyQuery(query) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) =>
    db.query(query, async (err, result) => {
      if (err) {
        reject(err)
      } else {
        resolve(result)
      }
    })
  )
}

async function dropAll() {
  console.log("ONE");
  const result = await promisifyQuery("SHOW tables")

  return Promise.all(result.map(async list => {
    await promisifyQuery(`DROP TABLE \`${list.Tables_in_gcd_updt}\``)
    console.log(list.Tables_in_gcd_updt + " REMOVED");

    console.log("TWO");
  }));
}

function getAll() {
  console.log("FOUR");
}

const infiniteQuestion = async function () {
  await prompt.question("What do you want to your DB project ?", async answer => {
    switch (answer) {
      case "drop":
        await dropAll();
        console.log("THREE");
        getAll();
        return infiniteQuestion();
      case "exit":
        console.log(`${answer} unknow`);
        rl.close();
        process.exit(0);
      default:
        return infiniteQuestion();
    }
  });
};

infiniteQuestion();
```

Comment: The `await` in front of `db.query("SHOW tables", async (err, result) => {` does not make any sense. It is unlikely that a function if it accepts and receives a `(err, result)` callback, will return a Promise. The `await` in front of `result.map(async list => {` does not make any sense, because of the callback in `map` not returning meaning useful Promise.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to wait for the first asynchronous function/instruction to finish before executing asynchronous second function/instruction you should put the second function/instruction inside callback of first. You will end up having a nested callback. Code demo using promises.

```
    function foo1()
      .then(el12 => {
        //logic for foo1
        function foo2()
          .then(ele2 => {
          //logic for foo2})
        })
    })
```

Second option is to use async/await.

```
async function main(){
   await function foo1()
   await function foo2()
}
```